# Create Facebook Session object and log from it

Tags: android, facebook, session, authentication, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm trying create a simple thing when user clicks the button then facebook login process should work. I did this with the deprecated methods and it FC the app before logging. In FB SDK 3.5 i have used session class to create that login by following many tutorials and they are also going FC at start on the activity. Here is my code,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

TextView username;
String APP_ID;
Button btn_login;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    APP_ID = getString(R.string.app_id);
    btn_login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
    btn_login.setOnClickListener(this);         

}       
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
              super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {    

    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback(){
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {

        }           
    });
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.facebookapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="@string/app_id" />

</application>
```

Is this way correct to have only a login function. If wrong please help me to how to do it on Facebook SDK 3.5 without native LoginButton system. Hope your kind answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this method:

```
 private boolean ensureOpenSession() {
    if (Session.getActiveSession() == null || !Session.getActiveSession().isOpened()) 
    {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
            {
                onSessionStateChanged(session, state, exception);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        onSessionStateChanged(Session.getActiveSession(), Session.getActiveSession().getState(), null);
    }
    return true;
}
```

and will have to create the `onSessionStateChanged` method:

```
 private void onSessionStateChanged(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
 {}
```

In which you can specify what happens when Session state changes.